# Validate object based on DTO object validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I want to validate my object from csv file based on my DTO *CustomerFailedPaymentDto* object before i process it. I use @Valid but still is not working.

Mycontroller.java

```
@PostMapping("/proccessFile")
    public String proccessFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

     // parse CSV file to create a list of `User` objects
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {

            // create csv bean reader
             CsvToBean<CustomerFailedPaymentDto> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                                .withType(CustomerFailedPaymentDto.class)
                                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                                .build();

            // I WANT TO VALIDATE THIS OBJECT                
            List <@Valid CustomerFailedPaymentDto> customerFailedPayment = csvToBean.parse();

            return virtualAccountService.buildFailedQuery(customerFailedPayment);                             

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           return "An error occurred while processing the CSV file.";
        }

    }
```

CustomerFailedPaymentDto.java

```
@Data
public class CustomerFailedPaymentDto {
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a bankPartner")
    private String bankPartner;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a bankCoreCode")
    private String bankCoreCode;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a transactionDate")
    private String transactionDate;
}
```

How to ensure that object i get from csv file is valid based on my DTO class validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation needs to be triggered, in your case spring doesn't do it.

Use `javax.validation.Validator`

Autowired Validator first

```
@Autowired
private final Validator validator;
```

Then for each list item validate using the validator.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomerFailedPaymentDto>> violations = validator.validate(perCustomerFailedPayment);
if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
  throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations));
}
```